# Enumerating internals of a multi-tab shell window in Windows 11

Tags: explorer, windows-11, microsoft-file-explorer

Suppose, we have a shell window with some folder, opened in Windows Explorer. It is possible to obtain IShellBrowser for this window, and from IShellBrowser, get inside the window (using the QueryActiveShellView method and further). The documentation for QueryActiveShellView states that the function returns the currently active (displayed) Shell view object.

In Windows 11, shell windows may have tabs. When this is the case, QueryActiveShellView returns the active tab. But how can one get inside the inactive tabs in a similar way? Is there an interface that would have some QueryInactiveShellViews method or another way to enumerate tabs and their views?